# Cycles and permutations

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

How many bijective functions from a set to itself containing a cycle that contains only 3 elements are there on the symmetric group (S4)?

My approach:

I understand that the formula is for l cycles in SN (symmetric group) is given by $nCl (l-1)!$ According to Wikipedia, but how do you prove it , and under what conditions does it fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the overview, as I've understood from the other answers and your approach:

- Directed cyclic graph, order matters.
- Distinct values only
- Ways to choose the start of the cycle.

The first and second points gives us 4 ways to pick the one we leave out, and 6 ways to order the 3 we do have. The last point is, that any three distinct elements, have three orderings in which you are simply moving the start point. Demonstration:

$$\begin{matrix}{\hspace{8pt}1\\\nearrow\searrow\\2\leftarrow3}& {\hspace{8pt}3\\\nearrow\searrow\\1\leftarrow2}&{\hspace{8pt}2\\\nearrow\searrow\\3\leftarrow1}\\{\hspace{8pt}1\\\nearrow\searrow\\2\leftarrow4}& {\hspace{8pt}4\\\nearrow\searrow\\1\leftarrow2}&{\hspace{8pt}2\\\nearrow\searrow\\4\leftarrow1}\\{\hspace{8pt}1\\\nearrow\searrow\\4\leftarrow3}& {\hspace{8pt}3\\\nearrow\searrow\\1\leftarrow4}&{\hspace{8pt}4\\\nearrow\searrow\\3\leftarrow1}\\{\hspace{8pt}4\\\nearrow\searrow\\2\leftarrow3}& {\hspace{8pt}3\\\nearrow\searrow\\4\leftarrow2}&{\hspace{8pt}2\\\nearrow\searrow\\3\leftarrow4}\\{\hspace{8pt}1\\\nearrow\searrow\\3\leftarrow2}& {\hspace{8pt}2\\\nearrow\searrow\\1\leftarrow3}&{\hspace{8pt}3\\\nearrow\searrow\\2\leftarrow1}\\{\hspace{8pt}4\\\nearrow\searrow\\2\leftarrow1}& {\hspace{8pt}1\\\nearrow\searrow\\4\leftarrow2}&{\hspace{8pt}2\\\nearrow\searrow\\1\leftarrow4}\\{\hspace{8pt}1\\\nearrow\searrow\\3\leftarrow4}& {\hspace{8pt}4\\\nearrow\searrow\\1\leftarrow3}&{\hspace{8pt}3\\\nearrow\searrow\\4\leftarrow1}\\{\hspace{8pt}4\\\nearrow\searrow\\3\leftarrow2}& {\hspace{8pt}2\\\nearrow\searrow\\4\leftarrow3}&{\hspace{8pt}3\\\nearrow\searrow\\2\leftarrow4}\end{matrix}$$ Note how the three in each row, simply rotate the others preserving order. The only difference, is in the value on top, of each triangle of arrows (Technically called $K_3$ I believe).

Answer (score 2):

No, this is incorrect.  You have found the total number of permutations on $\{1,2,3,4\}$ however several of these do not contain a cycle of order three, for example the permutation $(1~2)(3~4)$.

The error in your calculation is that you are counting the number of *strings* of length three that you can make in your set, but when interpreting them as cycles you have duplicates.  For example you counted $(1~2~3)$ to be different than $(2~3~1)$ and $(3~1~2)$ but in reality these are all the same cycle.

To correct your count, pick which three elements appear in your cycle simultaneously.  Then, fix the smallest element of them to the front of the cycle so that it appears in canonical form.  Finally, choose whether or not the largest remaining appears immediately to the right of the smallest in the cycle or not.

> This gives $\binom{4}{3}\cdot 2 = 8$ such cycles.  They are $(1~2~3),(1~3~2), (1~2~4),(1~4~2),(1~3~4),(1~4~3),(2~3~4),(2~4~3)$.

Comment: What do you mean by "pick which three elements appear in your cycle simultaneously?"

Comment: @topologicalmagician when determining a permutation with a cycle of length three, you will have three elements in the length three cycle... pick which three those are, but do so simultaneously.  In other words, do it in such a way so that order doesn't yet matter in our calculations.  Binomial coefficients count exactly this problem.  After having determined the set of digits to be used for the cycle, then decide how to arrange them within the cycle and recognize there are only two options once you take cyclic symmetry into account.

Comment: @topologicalmagician not quite.  Decide which three elements are in the 3-cycle.  Fix the smallest to the front of the cycle so it appears in canonical order.  Decide which order they appear in the 3-cycle.  From there, decide how the remaining two elements interact, whether they are each fixed points or whether they appear together in a 2-cycle.  We didn't have to concern ourselves with the remaining elements in the original problem because there was clearly only one way for them to appear since there was only one element remaining.  Now with more elements remaining, we had to pay attention.

Comment: @topologicalmagician Written in disjoint cyclic notation, the permutation $(1~2~3)(4)(5)$ is different than the permutation $(1~2~3)(4~5)$.  Rewritten as the two-line notation, $\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4&5\\2&3&1&5&4\end{pmatrix}$ is different than $\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4&5\\2&3&1&4&5\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: @topologicalmagician The canonical representation of a permutation in disjoint cyclic notation is the unique representation of the permutation such that the first entry in each cycle is the smallest entry of that cycle and the first entries of the cycles appear in increasing order.  $(1~4~6)(2)(3~5)$ is in fact the same permutation as $(2)(3~5)(4~6~1)$ as well as $(6~1~4)(5~3)(2)$ but only the first is an example of a permutation written in its canonical representation.  By ensuring we write things in canonical order that helps us avoid overcounting things unnecessarily as you have been.

Comment: @topologicalmagician "*I'm not sure what you mean by decide how the remaining two elements interact*"  When we were looking at the permutations of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ with a 3-cycle, we picked the three elements in the 3-cycle, and the order they appeared, an example outcome we have so far is having decided the 3-cycle looked like $(1~2~3)$.  But, this doesn't tell us information about $4$ or $5$ unless we make incorrect assumptions.  We need to decide whether we were looking at the permutation $(1~2~3)(4~5)$ or $(1~2~3)(4)(5)$, both of which are *different* and unequal permutations.  See above.

Answer (score 2):

Hint : note that $(123) =(312)=(231)$ or we have $24÷3=8$ answer .

Comment: Why don't you consider (4,3,1) for instance?

Comment: @topologicalmagician Amir does consider (4,3,1).  The answer is pointing out that in your attempt at counting you have triple counted every outcome and gave the three ways of counting (1,2,3) as an example, suggesting that you can correct your count by dividing by three.

Comment: @JMoravitz . Exactly.